# Maven Site Error: class file for org.jaxen.VariableContext not found

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to make the JavaDoc of my maven-project. So i added the plugin to my parent project and all of it sons have the same configuration by default. But unfortunately i have a big problem. When I run maven site into my project it throws this error: https://gist.github.com/rhuankarlus/8416752935567572e60f

I don't use the jaxen dependency in the project so I don't understand this error.
Googling it I found nothing.

Here's part of error message:

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] empresa Corporativo Root ............................. FAILURE [1:43.624s]
    [INFO] empresa Generico ..................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1:44.255s
    [INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 12 15:17:34 BRT 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 49M/237M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WARNING] The requested profile "template-config-empresa" could not be activated because it does not exist.
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project empresa-corporativo-root: Error during page generation: Error rendering Maven r
    eport:
    [ERROR] Exit code: 1 - Errors happened while accessing the package-list file at ../apidocs/
    [ERROR] Unable to access the package-list file at D:/Desenvolvimento/Repositorios/empresa-corporativo/trunk/target/javadoc-bundle-options/
    [ERROR] Errors happened while accessing the package-list file at ../apidocs/
    [ERROR] Unable to access the package-list file at D:/Desenvolvimento/Repositorios/empresa-corporativo/trunk/target/javadoc-bundle-options/
    [ERROR] Errors happened while accessing the package-list file at ../apidocs/
    [ERROR] Unable to access the package-list file at D:/Desenvolvimento/Repositorios/empresa-corporativo/trunk/target/javadoc-bundle-options/
    [ERROR] javadoc: warning - Error!
    [ERROR] javadoc: warning - com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jaxen.VariableContext not found
    [ERROR] com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jaxen.VariableContext not found
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'D:\Desenvolvimento\Repositorios\empresa-corporativo\trunk\target\site\testapidocs' dir.
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Please include the error message in the question itself.

Comment: I did not downvote.  Your question is now better because you included your error message.

Comment: did ou try to add jaxen dependency. looks like jaxen is needed to for some DOM manipulator APIs (dom4j). Take a look here [The type org.jaxen.VariableContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510618/the-type-org-jaxen-variablecontext-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: I've already added it to my project as maven dpendency and even manually but it doesn't work...

Comment: I had the same problem and adding jaxen as a maven dependency solved my problem